# Jquery Datatable ordering and rowReorder doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to make reorder the table and ordering the table but in this code block they doesn't work. Where is my issue?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.css"/>
```

**HTML**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="tdbicim">ID</th>
        <th id="tdbicim">Data One</th>
        <th id="tdbicim">Data Two</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="MyTbody"></tbody>
```

**JS**

```
var MyTbody = document.getElementById("MyTbody");

$('#MyTable').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": false,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "rowReorder": true
});

var Row = document.createElement("tr");
var Column = document.createElement("td");

Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data One Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data Two Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

// Add row
MyTbody.appendChild(Row);

Row = document.createElement("tr");
Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data One Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data Two Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

// Add row
MyTbody.appendChild(Row);

Row = document.createElement("tr");
Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("3"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data One Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data Two Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

// Add row
MyTbody.appendChild(Row);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/txsnyh66/

Answer (score 1):

Well I can say two things about your problem.

**1.** You are dynamically adding your rows after you initialized your datatable. So you can just initialize the datatable after you dynamically generate your table check this:

```js
var MyTbody = document.getElementById("MyTbody");
var Row = document.createElement("tr");
var Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data One Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data Two Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

MyTbody.appendChild(Row);

Row = document.createElement("tr");
Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data One Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data Two Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

MyTbody.appendChild(Row);

Row = document.createElement("tr");
Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("3"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data One Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

Column = document.createElement("td");
Column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Data Two Column"));
Row.appendChild(Column);

MyTbody.appendChild(Row);

// Initialize DataTable after table is generated
$('#MyTable').DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "searching": false,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": false,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "rowReorder": true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="MyTable" class="table table-bordered  ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="tdbicim">ID</th>
      <th id="tdbicim">Data One</th>
      <th id="tdbicim">Data Two</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="MyTbody">
  </tbody>

</table>
```

**2.** But if you want to dynamically generate your table I suggest you to use DataTable itself for this purpose like this:

```js
var dataSet = [
 [1, "Aaaa", "ddd"],
 [2, "DASD", "564"],
 [3, "HH", "dsdfd"],
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MyTable').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "ID" },
            { title: "Column 1" },
            { title: "Column 2" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="MyTable"></table>
```

I encourage you to go with solution number 2, it is much more cleaner and elegant. Good Luck!